# Occasional error in word finding genetic algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, genetic-algorithm

I (almost) successfully created a genetic algorithm to find a given string, but for some reason, I semi-frequently get an error when running the program, which otherwise works perfectly.

```
 Cannot read property 'dna' of undefined at Population.populate
```

I can't seem to figure out what causes this issue only a handful of times.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Word Search</title>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body style ='font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif'>
 Target: <input type='text' value='Hello World!'  id='target'> <br>
 Population Size: <input type='number' id='size' min='0' max='100' step='1' value='10'><br>
 Mutation Rate: <input type='number' id='rate' min='0' max='100' step='1' value='10'>%<br>
 <input type='submit' id='submit' onclick='evolution()'>
 <div  style='border-width: 2px; border-style: dashed; width: 250px'>
  <div style='text-align: center;' id='value'>
   <p id='generation';>Generation | 0</p>
   <div id='pop'>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">



window.onload = function() {
 evolution();
}

function evolution() {

 var population = new Population(
  document.getElementById('target').value, 
  document.getElementById('rate').value/100, 
  document.getElementById('size').value);

 var running = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
  population.natSelection();
  population.populate();
  population.evaluate();
  population.display();
  if(population.completed) {
   clearInterval(running);
   document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
  }
 }, 50);
}

function Population(target, mutationRate, size) {
 this.target = target;
 this.mutationRate = mutationRate;
 this.size = size;
 this.members = [];
 this.genePool = [];
 this.completed = false;
 this.generation = 0;

 for(var i = 0; i < this.size; i++)
  this.members.push(new Genome(this.target, this.mutationRate));

 this.natSelection = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.members.length; i++)
   this.members[i].calcFitness();
  
  this.genePool = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < this.members.length; i++)
   for(var j = 0; j < this.members[i].fitness*10; j++)
    this.genePool.push(this.members[i]);
 }

 this.populate = function() {
  this.generation++;
  this.members = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
   var a = this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)].dna;
   var b = this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)].dna;
   this.members.push(new Genome(this.target, this.mutationRate, a, b));
  }
 }

 this.evaluate = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
   if(this.members[i].dna === this.target)
    this.completed = true;
  }
 }

 this.calcMaxFitness = function() {
  var fittest = this.memebers[0].fitness; 
  for(var i = 1; i < this.members.length; i++)
   if(this.memebers[i].fitness > fittest)
    fittest = this.memebers[i].fitness;
  return fittest;
 }

 this.display = function() {
  document.getElementById('generation').innerHTML = 'Generation | '+this.generation;
  var div = document.getElementById('pop');
  div.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < this.members.length; i++) {
   div.innerHTML += this.members[i].dna+'<br>'
  }
 }
}

function Genome(target, mutationRate, parentA, parentB) {
 this.dna = '';
 this.fitness = 0;
 this.target = target;
 this.mutationRate = mutationRate;

 this.mutate = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) {
   if(this.dna.charCodeAt(i) != this.target.charCodeAt(i))
    if(Math.random() > this.mutationRate)
     this.dna = this.dna.replaceAt(i, String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*94+32)));
  }
 }

 if(!parentA && !parentB) {
  for(var i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++)
   this.dna += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random()*94+32));
 } else {
  var mid = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.target.length); 
  this.dna = parentA.substr(0, mid) + parentB.substr(mid, parentB.length);
  this.mutate();
 }
 
 this.calcFitness = function() {
  this.fitness = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) {
   if(this.dna.charCodeAt(i) === this.target.charCodeAt(i))
    this.fitness++;
  }
 }

}

Number.prototype.map = function (in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max) {
  return (this - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error happens when all members have a fitness of zero, then the loop in the `natSelection` function is looping until `j < this.members[i].fitness*10` which is zero, so no loop and nothing is added to `genePool`.

Now when that happens, obviously `this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)]` will be undefined and when you try to access the property `dna`, you get the error.

To solve this, you must add some validation so when all members have fitness of zero, you do something about it. Alternatively, at the end of the `natSelection` function, check `genePool.length` and if it is still zero, then add at least one item.

Comment: Of course! It is so obvious now, I didn't even think of that. Thanks for the help.
The solution that I have just implemented maps the fitness of each Genome from 0 to this.target.length, to 0.1 to this.target.length.

Answer (score 1):

## First, let's make sure we fully understand the error.

You are trying to read property `dna` of undefined in your `populate` method.

Said another way:

```
// Your populate method
this.populate = function() {
    this.generation++;
    this.members = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
        var a = this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)].dna;
        var b = this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)].dna;
        this.members.push(new Genome(this.target, this.mutationRate, a, b));
    }
}
```

JavasScript is seeing

```
this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)]
```

as `undefined`

and then, you're asking to JavaScript to read the `dna` property of `undefined`.

`undefined.dna`

## Now, let's figure out how we can debug the error.

Personally, I would log the following:

```
// Your populate method
this.populate = function() {
    this.generation++;
    this.members = [];

    console.log('SIZE', this.size);

    for(var i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {

        console.log('I', i);
        console.log('this.genePool', this.genePool);
        console.log('this.genePool.length', this.genePool.length);

        var a = this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)].dna;
        var b = this.genePool[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.genePool.length)].dna;
        this.members.push(new Genome(this.target, this.mutationRate, a, b));
    }
}
```

## Next, let's analyze the logs.

Maybe we have using `i < this.size` when we should be using `i < this.size - 1`, or something similar elsewhere (aka off-by-one error).

Maybe `this.genePool` is undefined sometimes.

If you still have trouble, update your question with some log output.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I have been working on fixing this issue for a while now, and I still can't seem to figure it out. My most recent attempt involve adding the line
    if(this.genePool.length < 1)
         this.natSelection();
so that if the genePool array doesn't exist the population would go through it's natural selection function again, and create a genePool, but for some reason that isn't solving anything either!